# UNET image segmentation testing results for colored images are not proper

Tags: python, image-segmentation, training-data

I have trained UNET image segmentation model with color images (with Ground Truth also in color), and testing for an image but not getting output as segmented image, getting blank colored image... I have trained model for 2 epochs with 50 images, got training accuracy about 98% and training loss got is about 58%. Whats the problem?

Comment: unbalanced data.

Comment: In case of image how you define unbalanced data??

Comment: in terms of labels: it might be the case that most of your labels (pixels) belongs to "bg" class and only small portion belongs to other classes.

Comment: "bg" means Back Ground ?? if yes then may be you are saying correctly, but still not getting.

Comment: I am working on Brain tumor segmentation project, label images are violet in color and having only Yellow Patch indicating tumorous region. In this way labels are in only two colors Violet and Yellow... now you say...  And @shai Thanks for replying and helping me...

Comment: what is the percent of "violet" labels out of all labeled pixels? 98%? if so, what would be the accuracy of a model that labels all pixels as "violet"?

Comment: Yes in every label image/GT image, you can consider violet color as 90% and Yellow color only 10% indicating tumor region. But if you are working like Brain tumor segmentation then only possibility of Ground Truth images are like above means 90% back-ground and 10% tumorous part any where located in GT image. So what you will suggest me?? how I would proceed?? How my training data?? or can I go with Gray Scale images only?? colored images are not working in this??Thanks again